# Changing the working hours on a room mailbox in Outlook/Exchange

Tags: exchange

I setup a Room resource recipient in Exchange so that users could book the associated conference room. This part works, but when I attempt to view the room's schedule in Scheduling Assistant, the room shows as Out of Office for regular working hours.

[image: Scheduling Assistant screenshot]

I've tried searching for a solution to this problem and found [this other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/452571/room-mailbox-and-room-calender), but the room does not appear in `Recipient Mailboxes`, but `Recipient Resources` and therefore has different settings than those described. I have not found any way to configure working hours for the room in the resource settings, either. How can I either align the Out of Office hours for the room with the rest of the team, or else remove them entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, working hours of resource mailboxes are 8:00 A.M. to 5:00 P.M. Monday through Friday.

You can refer to this command to check the working hours of this resource mailbox:

```
get-MailboxCalendarConfiguration -Identity <PrimartySMTPofRoomResource> |select-object WorkingHours*
```

If the working hours for this mailbox is incorrect, you can run the following command to change the time:

```
Set-MailboxCalendarConfiguration -Identity <PrimartySMTPofRoomResource>
-WorkingHoursStartTime 08:00:00 -WorkingHoursEndTime 17:00:00
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are you aware if there's a package I have to install to have access to these commands? They don't seem to be present on my installation of PowerShell.

Comment: Yes.  You need to install the ExchangeOnlineManagement module and connect to Exchange Online PowerShell with Global Administrator or Exchange Administrator.
For specific information, you could refer to the following links:
[About the Exchange Online PowerShell V2 module and V3 module | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps)
[Connect to Exchange Online Protection PowerShell | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-protection-powershell?view=exchange-ps)

Comment: Looking at the module, I don't see either of the commands you mentioned in there.

Comment: Sorry, nevermind, it was there. I was just being dumb >_<